# Preloading (just) an object (e.g. video)(rather than whole website) with preloader screen using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking for a specific implementation of any of the preloading page js/jquery plugins.
I've created a single page website (mostly using Skeleton) that has a hero page with a fullscreen background video. I've kept the video length short (8s), removed the audio and thus managed a relatively small size of around 1mb. Still, I would prefer the video to preload before the actual hero page appears (only for aesthetic reasons--it's a band's website that "needs to impress").
So,
- I do need the page loading overlay (which I'm comfortable creating in html5/css3)
- I only need the video to preload rather than the rest of the page (fonts, images et.c.)
I do have found scipts/plugins that can load the whole page but I'm looking for that little change in the code to only preload the specific id (the div or video tag containing the video if I get it right) and then immediately hide the loading overlay.
I prefer this because page has many external embeds (videos, bandcamp players) plus images that take a while to load but lie towards the end of the page.

Thank you in advance. K.

Comment: Please provide sample code and information what you've already tried.

Comment: I've been using this [link](https://github.com/niklausgerber/PreLoadMe) that works like a charm. I'm just trying to make it preload just the video--rather than the whole page--before fading out.

Comment: (Sorry, I can't get how to post code using the 4 spaces before...)